# grub broken and wont boot

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-7, grubrescue

i had ubuntu 12.10 running allongside with windows 7 (dual boot, 1 hdd). when installing ubuntu i accidentally gave it too much room. so i decided that i would remove it and reinstall it but this time on a 100gb partition instead of a 300. so in windows i removed the ubuntu partition and extended my win7 partition back to 913 then i hibernated windows to see if it worked... as it turns out grub is still here and now when i boot it says "no such partition" and im in a grub recovery console... any idea how to get back into windows? PLEASE i need it!

*EDIT* I need to fix this ASAP. PLEASE. my windows 7 is hibernated and i cant partition my hdd to install ubuntu again to fix this. I NEED HELP. is there a command i can type inside of the grub recovery console just to boot to win 7?

Comment: forgo to mention that right now the only to use my computer is to boot from a ubuntu live cd. i cant do anything

Comment: You can always edit your question to give additional info - better than commenting!

Comment: This solve me problem:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/546839/gnu-grub-minimal-bash-like-line-editing-screen-displays-before-the-usual-grub-s All you have to do is type exit and press enter.

Answer (score 1):

You deleted the Ubuntu partition, in turn deleting `/boot` which is where GRUB lives. The simple way is to reinstall Ubuntu and all shall be peaceful...

Comment: Also I think that there's windows uninstall client which is good way how to remove linux in short time without problems.

Comment: ...yes but i only want it on a 100gb partition but idk how to make one in ubuntu. and when i install ubuntu it makes me partition but it is not clearley labled so i dont know what to do.

Comment: is there any way i can just make grub let me boot into windows?

Comment: GRUB is not installed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

fixed it. i just went to http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/ and it fixed it. but i think grub is gone but i dont care. i got my win 7 back.
thanks everyone for your time!

Answer (score 0):

When you deleted the Ubuntu partition you broke Grub because it needs the Boot information from there.

Without an Ubuntu partition you cannot boot Windows with Grub.

You have two options:

1. Reinstall Ubuntu on the reduced partition. This will reinstall Grub and you'll be able to boot Windows and Ubuntu with Grub again.
2. If you do not want to install Ubuntu again, then repair your MBR, practically removing Grub and restoring the Windows bootloader. You will need a Windows install CD or a substitute. You boot from a repair disc or install disc, go to the command prompt and run `bootrec.exe /FixMbr` followed by `bootrec.exe /FixBoot`. See [this site](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/win7-windows-7-mbr,10036.html) for more details.

Comment: can ubuntu still install even if windows is hibernated?

Comment: I think it could install just the same

Comment: what do you mean on the reduced partition. my windows is hibernated and i dont think it will install on it

Comment: Create a new partition in the space left by the deletion of the old Ubuntu installation.

Comment: well... theres a problem. i put that back into my hard drive... so now its 1 913gb hdd and its hibernated...

Comment: i cant. i tryed to reinstall but it failed becasue windows is hibernated

Answer (score 0):

Windows may be hibernating, but if you reboot and install Ubuntu it will be fine.  The reboot puts Ubuntu in charge, so Windows snoozing is irrelevant.