# Grub error minimal bash like line editing is supported

Tags: grub2

This question is similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546839) but I have a slight modification.

In that question their Ubuntu opens after typing `exit` in the command window at which point the error is displayed. After selecting again the OS again, the Ubuntu is opening without any issues.

However, for me Ubuntu is not opening - even after clicking exit in the command window, where the error is displayed, and selecting the Ubuntu os again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please refer to the link provided below if you have come across the same grub error.
        http://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/

The above link will provide you a clear solution of the error that you occured and how to sove it.This worked for me and hope it will work for you too.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the main points from your link in your answer, in case the link becomes unavailable in the future.

Comment: Also, if these instructions successfully resolved your problem, then please accept your answer by clicking the checkmark icon next to it. This will properly mark the question as resolved. Thanks!