# Cant boot up my pc bc GNU GRUB

Tags: grub2, bash, versions, gnu

So my pc saying when 7 boot

GNU GRUB version 2.06
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

What should i do now?

Comment: Do you happen to know which partition is your root partition, ie sda1, 2 ,3, 4 .... sdb 1 ,2, 3, 4 etc. If not it can be easily found from the grub prompt.

Comment: No i dont would be nice if uhelped found out

Comment: OK. Boot into your  USB installer drive. Then open terminal. and type **sudo parted -l**. Post up output from that into your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GNU GRUB, Minimal BASH-like line editing screen displays before the usual GRUB screen when dual-booting Ubuntu 14 and Windows 8.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546839/gnu-grub-minimal-bash-like-line-editing-screen-displays-before-the-usual-grub-s)